# Map comparison operators to function call

Tags: python

I'm building a DSL for form validation in Python, and one of the requirements is to be able to specify that a field should be greater than or less than a constant or another field value. As a result, I'm trying to easily map operators like `<`, `>`, `<=` and `>=` to their equivalent functions in the `operator` module, so that they can be called during field validation.

I realise I could just create a dictionary to map the operator to the function, but is there a nicer way to do it? Is there any way to access Python's built-in mapping?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what exactly are you trying to achieve.
Python 'maps' these operators to class' own implementation of according methods, like `__cmp__`, `__eq__`, `__ne__` and so on, and exact mapping to actual comparsion function depends on the class.

Comment: Absolutely. So somewhere in Python is some logic that knows that when it sees `<`, it should call `obj.__lt__`. But I have a string, `'<'` - how can I convert it to a function or method call?

Comment: Can you give an in-context example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there is no built-in dictionary mapping the string `">"` to the function `operator.lt`, etc.

As others have pointed out, the Python interpreter itself does not make use of such a dictionary, since the process of parsing and executing Python code will first translate the character sequence ">" to a token representing that operator, which will then be translated to bytecode, and the result of executing that bytecode will execute the `__lt__` method directly, rather than via the `operator.lt` function.

Answer (score 3):

Python's internal mapping of "<" to `__lt__` (and so on) isn't exposed anywhere in the standard library.  There's a lot about Python's internals that aren't exposed as a toolkit.  I'm not even sure in general how such a mapping would be created.  What maps onto `__getitem__`?

You'll just have to create your own mapping.  It shouldn't be difficult.